# How to hide multiple sets of columns in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to hide certain columns when a macro is run. How do I do this?

I know how to do it by a range of columns `("B:D")` using:

```
Columns("B:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

But I'm not sure how to specify multiple columns that are not next to each other.

I would need to hide columns: B, C, F, G, I, J, K, L, N.

Comment: Record Macro gives very good hints. It will result in something like the answer below, but with the correct `,N:N` at the end

Comment: Thanks @Slai - I hadn't noticed that the "N" by itself wouldn't be a valid range specification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Range("B:C,F:G,I:L,N:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

(Edited to fixed the bug noticed by Slai - have to have "N:N" and not just "N".)

Comment: use ``` Columns(col0 & ":" & col1).Hidden = TRUE``` instead, 'entireColumn' for some reason is super slow